# Bootstrap 4 DatePicke issue

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4, jQuery 3.3.1 and datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

I have three issues:

1. The Calendar icon is not the size of the input box
2. When submit without selecting the date, bootstrap validation message not working.
3. Auto close is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#depositeDate').datepicker({
    "setDate": new Date(),
    "autoclose": true
    });
})


<div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="depositeDate" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">Deposit Date</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-2 input-group date">
                       <input type="text" class=" text-input form-control"  id ="depositeDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">                                                                 
                                <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-3x" style="color:RED"></i>                             </div>                          
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                          Please enter a valid Order Number.
                        </div>
                      </div>                        
                </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The Calendar icon is not the size of the input box

The markup for [input group addon](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/input-group/) is changed in Bootstrap 4.0 stable

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your code should be

```
<div class="input-group date" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  id ="depositeDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
        <div class="input-group-append">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span></span>

        </div>
    </div>
```

> 3.Auto close is not working.

I don't see setting like `"autoclose": true` , we should explicitly call to close the datepicker.

```
.on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  checkout.hide();
})
```

Comment: Calendar icon is still small than the height of the text field.

Comment: @user3067524 Add the class fa-2x to the icon `<span class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></span>`, if that does not work for you, you need to set the font size for the icon.

Comment: I have tried this below and everything looks good except a small issue. If I click on  input field, calendar is popping up but calendar icon was not clickable, Please see updated code.

Comment: Move the` id ="depositeDate"` to `<div class="input-group date" id ="depositeDate">`

Comment: kiranvj- Did you understand my question ? the Calendar icon was not Clickable (I cannot click on Calendar icon to get the calendar popup). Anyway I tried moving ID to "input-group date" that did not work.

Comment: To expand on this, if you add input-group-addon as a class after input-group-append, the icon cursor changes on mouseover of the icon

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <label for="depositeDate" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Deposit Date</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-3 input-group date" >
                       <input type="text" class="text-input form-control" id ="depositeDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
                        <div class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="$('#depositeDate').focus();">
                            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt fa-2x"></i>
                        </div>                                                                                
                      </div>                        
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will do:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">




<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Order number">Order number</label>
        <input type="text" id="Order number" >


      </div>


      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <label for="male">Deposit Date</label>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});</script>
```

check out the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/rqy7L2do/